# MongoDB: Querying for a referenced document

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am new to MongoDB and I read the MongoDB documentation. I have following structure: -

```
public class User
{
    [BsonId]
    public long UserId { get; set; }        
    public string LoginId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }        
    public List<string> Gateways { get; set; }
}
public class Gateway
{
    [BsonId]
    public string MACAddress { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

I referenced Gateway MAC Addresses in the USER document as Gateway is also having separate existence in absence of USER. For getting all the gateways for a given `UserId` I am writing queries as follows: -

```
var userQuery = Query<User>.EQ(u => u.UserId, aUserId);
var userCursor = mMongoUserCollection.Find(userQuery);
var gateways = mMongoGatewayCollection.AsQueryable<Gateway>().Where(g => userCursor.FirstOrDefault().Gateways.Contains(g.MACAddress));
```

But I am getting an Exception that

```
"Unable to determine Serialization Information for the expression: Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<User>"
```

But when I write my query as follows all goes well

```
var userQuery = Query<User>.EQ(u => u.UserId, aUserId);
var userCursor = mMongoUserCollection.Find(userQuery);

List<string> desiredGateways = userCursor.FirstOrDefault().Gateways;
var gateways = mMongoGatewayCollection.AsQueryable<Gateway>().Where(g => desiredGateways.Contains(g.MACAddress));
```

I just want to know the difference between the above two.

Comment: Don't use JOINS or use an RDBMS instead. MongoDB does not do JOIN's . Either fully embed all the data in the "Gateways" List element. Or just accept that each document only contains a `List` of the valid `_id` values. You can submit other queries to resolve those, but that is exactly the only way to do it. By submitting another query..

Comment: @Neil Lunn, I got your point but please also provide your views on my queries that I have edited in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the MongoDB C# driver can't translate the first snippet into a MongoDB query, while it can the second one.

When you call `Where` on an `IQueryable` it stores all the lambda expressions until you materialize the query be using `foreach` or `ToList`. At that stage the provider (the driver) tries to generate relevant queries to be performed in the database.

The database can't use `userCursor.FirstOrDefault()` as it doesn't know what `FirstOfDefault` is and it can't receive a cursor. It can however serialize a `User` instance that you have retrieved from the database previously.